How do I make library and expose part of it in Kotlin
I have a singleton manage all database requests and I want to compile it as a separate lib and use it's API in other project, how do I do so?
for example:
class DatabaseManager() {
    companion object {
        private val TAG = "DatabaseManager"
        @Volatile
        private var instance: DatabaseManager? = null

        fun getInstance() =
            instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: DatabaseManager().also { instance = it }
            }
    }

    fun a(){}
    fun b(){}
    fun c(){}
}

I want to compile it as a separate lib and expose just a() and b(), to add it as dependency at a different project and reuse the code.

What have you tried exactly?

nothing yet, I did it with c++ lib with simple makefile and used JNI with Java code but never with Kotlin

Why are you going to all those lengths to create a singleton? Just write object DatabaseManager { fun a() {} etc } and you're done!

I have a suspicion that this is Java code that was automatically migrated to Kotlin via the IDE, or they're using Java best practices :)

@k314159, just read about it, thanks

The Gradle docs are pretty good for this kind of thing https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_kotlin_libraries.html#assemble_the_library_jar

it's an open class inherits from activity so it easier to use singleton with getInstace from companion object. it's just a dummy example
